# running powershell command does not take the piped value

Tags: powershell

please tell me what wrong with this syntax:

```
$computername = 'moti10'
copy C:\sylink\sylink.xml \\$computername\c$\intel\
copy C:\sylink\SylinkDrop.exe \\$computername\c$\intel\
copy c:\sylink\SylinkDropCommand.xml \\$computername\c$\intel\
cd "C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\pstools\"
psexec" $computername -d -h c:\intel\sylinkdrop.exe
```

1. it does not copy the files to the destination computer
2. `psexec` does not run - "the string is missing the terminator"

Comment: Powershell? I don't see any Powershell. Also, you have a quote after Psexec, but no corresponding quote at the end of the line.

Answer (score 2):

`PSexec` requires the computer name to be prefaced with the double `\\` that indicates you are connecting to a remote system. As for the failure to copy, you may want to fully quote the remote path you are copying the files to, and specify the  `-destination` parameter:

```perl
$computername = "moti10"
copy C:\sylink\sylink.xml -destination "\\$computername\c$\intel\"
copy C:\sylink\SylinkDrop.exe -destination "\\$computername\c$\intel\"
copy c:\sylink\SylinkDropCommand.xml -destination "\\$computername\c$\intel\"
cd "C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\pstools\"
psexec \\$computername -d -h c:\intel\sylinkdrop.exe
```

(Syntax highlighting seems to be broken, it appears to think there's a stray quote.)